# Automated size for cells in IGListCollectionsVeiw with section headers don't work

Tags: swift, iglistkit

I have an IGListCollectionView with sectionHeaders.
How do I auto size the cells

I need to present info in a table with different cells height in same section, each section have a sticky header.
I am using SectionController that inherit from ListBindingSectonControllerDataSource.
I tray to use estimatedItemSize and headerReferenceSize.

The UI is bouncy - look like it have a problem to calculate the header size.
If I run the code without the header it works fine.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?